# Why does referendum on a local chain always fail in execution with BadOrigin?

Tags: governance

In trying to learning how governance works, I have implemented a bare-minimum governance configuration. I run it on a local relay chain and passed referenda always fail enactment with `BadOrigin` no matter what extrinsic is proposed. Even a simple balance transfer initiated by the origin account for the transfer fails. All proposals are proposed by a Council member, using the Polkadot UI -> Democracy tab. Everything else works as expected. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Here is my governance-related config:

```
parameter_types! {
    pub MaximumSchedulerWeight: Weight = Perbill::from_percent(10) * RuntimeBlockWeights::get().max_block;
    pub const MaxScheduledPerBlock: u32 = 50;
    pub const NoPreimagePostponement: Option<u32> = Some(5 * MINUTES);
}

impl pallet_scheduler::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Origin = Origin;
    type PalletsOrigin = OriginCaller;
    type Call = Call;
    type MaximumWeight = MaximumSchedulerWeight;
    type ScheduleOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type MaxScheduledPerBlock = MaxScheduledPerBlock;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_scheduler::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type OriginPrivilegeCmp = EqualPrivilegeOnly;
    type PreimageProvider = Preimage;
    type NoPreimagePostponement = NoPreimagePostponement;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const PreimageMaxSize: u32 = 4096 * 1024;
    pub const PreimageBaseDeposit: Balance = 1 * MILLIUNIT;
    pub const PreimageByteDeposit: Balance = 1 * MICROUNIT;
}

impl pallet_preimage::Config for Runtime {
    type WeightInfo = pallet_preimage::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type Event = Event;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type ManagerOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type MaxSize = PreimageMaxSize;
    type BaseDeposit = PreimageBaseDeposit;
    type ByteDeposit = PreimageByteDeposit;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const CouncilMotionDuration: BlockNumber = 5 * DAYS;
    pub const CouncilMaxProposals: u32 = 25;
    pub const CouncilMaxMembers: u32 = 1;
}

type CouncilCollective = pallet_collective::Instance1;
impl pallet_collective::Config<CouncilCollective> for Runtime {
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Proposal = Call;
    type Event = Event;
    type MotionDuration = CouncilMotionDuration;
    type MaxProposals = CouncilMaxProposals;
    type MaxMembers = CouncilMaxMembers;
    type DefaultVote = pallet_collective::PrimeDefaultVote;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_collective::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const LaunchPeriod: BlockNumber = 28 * 24 * 60 * MINUTES;
    pub const VotingPeriod: BlockNumber = 28 * 24 * 60 * MINUTES;
    pub const FastTrackVotingPeriod: BlockNumber = 3 * 24 * 60 * MINUTES;
    pub const MinimumDeposit: Balance = 100 * UNIT;
    pub const EnactmentPeriod: BlockNumber = 30 * 24 * 60 * MINUTES;
    pub const CooloffPeriod: BlockNumber = 28 * 24 * 60 * MINUTES;
    pub const MaxProposals: u32 = 100;
}

impl pallet_democracy::Config for Runtime {
    type CooloffPeriod = CooloffPeriod;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type EnactmentPeriod = EnactmentPeriod;
    type Event = Event;
    type FastTrackVotingPeriod = FastTrackVotingPeriod;
    type InstantAllowed = frame_support::traits::ConstBool<true>;
    type LaunchPeriod = LaunchPeriod;
    type MaxProposals = MaxProposals;
    type MaxVotes = ConstU32<100>;
    type MinimumDeposit = MinimumDeposit;
    type PreimageByteDeposit = PreimageByteDeposit;
    type Proposal = Call;
    type Scheduler = Scheduler;
    type Slash = (); 
    type WeightInfo = pallet_democracy::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type VoteLockingPeriod = EnactmentPeriod; // Same as EnactmentPeriod
    type VotingPeriod = VotingPeriod;
    type ExternalDefaultOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 1, 1>;
    type ExternalMajorityOrigin =  pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 3, 4>;
    type ExternalOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 1, 2>;
    type FastTrackOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type InstantOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type PalletsOrigin = OriginCaller;
    type CancellationOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 2, 3>;
    type CancelProposalOrigin = EitherOfDiverse<EnsureRoot<AccountId>,  pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 1, 1>>;
    type BlacklistOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type VetoOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureMember<AccountId, CouncilCollective>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Democracy proposal executes, it dispatches the call using the `Root` origin:

```rust
let res = proposal
    .dispatch(frame_system::RawOrigin::Root.into())
    .map(|_| ())
    .map_err(|e| e.error);
```

This means you need to call extrinsics which expect the `Root` origin, else you will get a `BadOrigin` error.

For example, the `transfer` function in Balances expects a signed origin:

```rust
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::transfer())]
pub fn transfer(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    dest: AccountIdLookupOf<T>,
    #[pallet::compact] value: T::Balance,
) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
    let transactor = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    // -- snip --
}
```

And this makes sense, because if you execute a transfer from a democracy proposal, who will be the sender account which has the original balance to be transferred?

You might want to try calling `force_transfer` instead, which is specifically a `Root` call for transferring the balance on behalf of another user:

```rust
/// Exactly as `transfer`, except the origin must be root and the source account may be
/// specified.
/// # <weight>
/// - Same as transfer, but additional read and write because the source account is not
///   assumed to be in the overlay.
/// # </weight>
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::force_transfer())]
pub fn force_transfer(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    source: AccountIdLookupOf<T>,
    dest: AccountIdLookupOf<T>,
    #[pallet::compact] value: T::Balance,
) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
    ensure_root(origin)?;
    let source = T::Lookup::lookup(source)?;
    let dest = T::Lookup::lookup(dest)?;
    <Self as Currency<_>>::transfer(
        &source,
        &dest,
        value,
        ExistenceRequirement::AllowDeath,
    )?;
    Ok(().into())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, I had suspected as much but wasn't sure.